# Unable to connect to mySQL database during Joomla installation

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, installation

I want to host a Website with Joomla on my Windows Server. Therefor I installed PHP and MySQL and downloaded the newest Joomla distribution.

I created a database and a user in MySQL with the following SQL:

```
create database joomlaintranet;
CREATE USER 'joomlaintranetuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'abc';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON joomlaintranet.* To 'joomlaintranetuser'@'localhost';
```

However when I start the Joomla Installation process by opening the site in a WebBrowser and then Enter the Database Information I get a 'Could not connect to MySQL server.' Error.

[image]

With the Shell or Workbench I can login with the given credentials. I checked also for Error Logs but didn't find any Entries in the MySQL Logs.

When checking online for similiar problems the only reasons I found where Typos or wrong Host entrences.

Comment: I would like to invite you to join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and post your question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue thx to [Webdongle](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=707&t=975508&p=3585554#p3585554) from the Joomla Forum.

The issue I was facing was due to the new SHA-256 Password Encryption introduced in MySQL 8. With witch PHP and therefor Joomla can't deal yet.

Since my MySQL installation was only for the purpose of this Website, I just reinstalled it with the Legacy Authentication Method for now.

[image]

Theres also [this](https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_and_MySQL_8) Workaround possible.